# python shape data problem newbies how can i reshape my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This is my dataframe in Excl format:

[image: This is my dataframe in Excl format]

I am confused that what algorithm can I use to change the dataframe so it can be like this?
[image: Shape i want]

Do you guys have any idea for that?

I already tried some groupby but it doesn't work, so I don't know what library I can use because I cannot imagine how to do it

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7586ac815d63> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.pivot(index='Drug',columns='QtyDelivered')

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py in _make_selectors(self)
    187 
    188         if mask.sum() < len(self.index):
--> 189             raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
    190 
    191         self.group_index = comp_index

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Comment: 1. Please next time add actual code and a reproducible example to your question. 2. Use pandas pivot function - your exact required reshaping is in the documentation.

Comment: What about adding it _this_ time already? That would tremendously help answering the question, I suppose.